# URL to My Account in Django Template

Tags: django, django-templates

I am new to django and would like to have a link in my navigation bar called "My Account" when it is clicked I would like it to go to the users account page which is at http://myurl.com/twitter/detail/username. I know it is something simple to get this to work I just don't know how to do it. So my question is what would the My Account href look like in my template, something like {% url 'something i don't know' %}

My Detail View:

```
url(r'^detail/(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use url tag with url name and parameter if any like this:

```
{% url 'detail' username=request.user.username %}
```

Comment: and how would I call the current username? for example {% url 'detail' username=CURRENT_USER %}

Comment: `{% url detail username=request.user.username %}`?

Comment: @SeanPapanikolas Edited for clarity.